# I want update from one table to another table based on true or false condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, mssql-jdbc

I have one table that contains several tasks which is belongs to some categories and one column called 'completed' which tells particular task is completed or not, based on this status I want to update  as 'completed' for particular category in another table which contains categories. How to do in MS SQL query? Here, for 'completed' column I am using bit as datatype.

Comment: Could you provide the table schema and some sample data and expected result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Update table category set complete = True where name In
(
    select distinct t.category
    from task t
    where task.complete = true And not exists (
        select t1.category
        from task t1
        where t1.category = t.category And t1.complete = false
    )
)
```

Comment: I want to update two table based on single button click from webpage. How to do in single stored procedure? . plz consider above same scenario.

Comment: @Tarun I think you should try to update one table at a time. And you wrap the two queries updating the two tables in a transaction.

Answer (score 0):

You may create a AFTER INSERT TRIGGER on your first table thus you can update your second table column value referencing your status column value in the earlier.